# How to forward appharbor domain to my custom domain

Tags: dns, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

I have a web site ([Tulpep](http://www.tulpep.com)) app runing in [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/).
The default domain in appharbor is http://tulpepwebsite.apphb.com/.

The site is running on ASP.NET MVC 4.5.

Is it possible to redirect the users if in some case they visit the *apphb.com  domain to my custom domain?

I think it may be not possible because the redirection from my custom domain to my apphb.com domain is made by a DNS from www to tulpepwebsite.apphb.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [canonical hostname](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/canonical-hostname) on AppHarbor.

Comment: If I have a wilcard hostname, the page doesnt allow me. So I need yo change *.tulpep.com to www.tulpep.com. I have to pay the $10US again?

Comment: It's $10 per application, so once you've paid that you can add all the hostnames you need. You should probably add both `*.tulpep.com` and `www.tulpep.com` and make `www.tulpep.com` the canonical hostname.